# Unity manage GUI in Multiple levels / scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm new to Unity. I'm making the Unity 2D game with multiple levels/scenes.

In my scene I will have `moving objects` created from prefabs, `GUI` (pause button, menu button, text current score, text high score, etc.), and also I want to create `two UI panels` with their own UI components, one for level passed and the other for level failed.

As I know, I need to create a new scene/level from the menu to add a new one which is empty. 
Should I make a copy of all the GUI buttons and panels on every new scene/level, or is there any way to reuse these GUI components?

> I must use new levels, not randomly generated levels all the time

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I know I need to create new scene/ level from the menu to add new one
>   which is empty. My question is should I make a copy of all the GUI
>   buttons and panels on every new scene/level, or is there any way to
>   reuse these GUI components?

Create the UI in one scene then convert them into a prefab save it. This prefab can be re-used and modified from other scenes. Prefab is what you should be using when you need to share items between scenes. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wS5f0OKucxM) video shows how to create prefab from an Object in the scene.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can I create prefabs from Camera, is this good practice ?

Comment: You can if you need the-same camera settings in another scene. It's fine